# Clarification needed: core differences between two receipt selection code snippets

Tags: java, comparison, code-analysis

I've been going through some exam questions and stumbled upon two different implementations for a receipt selection task. I'm trying to understand the key differences between these two code snippets. The first code snippet is my own, and the second one is from the exam question.

**Code Example 1:**

```java
public static Receipt[] selectReceipts(Receipt[] receipts, String currency) {

    int countReceipts = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < receipts.length; i++) {
        if (receipts[i].getCurrency().equals(currency)) {
            countReceipts++;
        } else {
            i++; 
        }
    }

    Receipt[] newReceipts = new Receipt[countReceipts];

    for (int i = 0; i < receipts.length; i++) {
        if (receipts[i].getCurrency().equals(currency)) {
            newReceipts[i] = receipts[i];
        }
    }

    return newReceipts; 
}
```

**Code Example 2:**

```java
public static Receipt[] selectReceipts(Receipt[] receipts, String currency) {

    int countReceipts = 0;
    for (Receipt receipt : receipts) {
        if (receipt.getCurrency().equals(currency)) {
            countReceipts++;
        }
    }

    Receipt[] selectedReceipts = new Receipt[countReceipts];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (j < countReceipts) {
        if (receipts[i].getCurrency().equals(currency)) {
            selectedReceipts[j++] = receipts[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    return selectedReceipts;
}
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could shed light on this. What are the significant differences between the `for` loop structure in my Code Example 1 and the combination of `for-each` and `while` loops in Code Example 2? Is the inclusion of the `else` statement in my Code Example 1 necessary? Additionally, should I consider renaming the `newReceipts` array for better clarity?

And finally, does the code functionally achieve the same thing? My own code is Example 1, so in all likelihood, if there's an error, it would be there.

I received some valuable insights regarding the potential issues in my code. Specifically, there seems to be a bug in my first example's second loop where the newReceipts array might be of a shorter length compared to the receipts array, potentially leading to incorrect results.

Comment: There are a couple of things in your own code that can potentially get you an "array out of bound" error. The "else" statement needs to be removed as it causes receipts to be skipped while you are counting. Secondly, the statement "newReceipts[i] = receipts[i]" needs to be changed to "newReceipts[j++] = receipts[i]" where j should be defined and initialized to 0 before the for loop.